# how to ask turtle move to the nearest patche with the same category?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to change the location of problem youth if police visits it. The design of the model is I set the patches with different categories, problem youth (turtle) occupies a patch with category "school" or "supermarket", if police(turtle) visit this patch, the problem youth should change its location to the nearest patch with category "school" or "supermarket". The code I wrote does not work, it showed the problem youth does not move when the police visit, it still occupies the same patch.

Any help will be so appreciated.

```
to change-location
  let nearest-police min-one-of police [distance myself]
  if distance nearest-police = 0 [
    let target-patch one-of patches with [category = "school" or category = "supermarket"]
    if  target-patch != one-of patches with [[category = "school"] of myself or [category = "supermarket"] of myself] and distance target-patch > 0 [
      go-to target-patch
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: I have formatted the code (use the { } icons when creating your question). Please check it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If I have interpreted your question correctly, the patch variable named 'category' takes the values of "school", "supermarket" and potentially other options. What you want is to restrict the choice to patches with the same category as the patch that the asking turtle is already on.

Your code `one-of patches with [[category = "school"] of myself or [category = "supermarket"] of myself]` doesn't really make sense. If this is the bit that is supposed to select the patches with the correct category, just replace this with: `one-of other patches with [category = [category] of myself]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, JenB. Yes, I want to move the turtle to the nearest patch with the same category as the patch that the asking turtles is already on. The problem is how to avoid if the turtle takes the current patch it is already on as the target patch? Because the turtle stays at the current patch sometimes when I running this mdel. I tried your code, the Runtime Error came out  to 'one of' which is "WITH expected a true/false value from (patch 422 634), but got school instead."

Comment: edited the code - `other` avoids the same patch problem

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks a lot!